# what is equivalent of catalog_category_entity_url_key in magento2?

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, url-key

I am trying to find category url keys and I have catalog_category_entity_url_key in magento1, but I do not have it in magento2. how can I find the values?

Comment: M2 store category URL key in catalog_category_varchar. Hope this will help you.

Comment: thank you yea I saw that but I thought maybe there is more to that

Answer (score 0):

You can get all of the Categories from this Query of Database:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cc.entity_id as id, cc.value as path, cc1.value as name    
  FROM catalog_category_entity_varchar cc    
  JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar cc1 ON cc.entity_id=cc1.entity_id    
  JOIN eav_entity_type ee ON cc.entity_type_id=ee.entity_type_id
  JOIN catalog_category_entity cce ON cc.entity_id=cce.entity_id
  WHERE cc.attribute_id = '57' AND cc1.attribute_id = '41' AND ee.entity_model = 'catalog/category';
```

Now comes to catalog_category_entity_url_key comes under catalog_category_varchar.